# Flask and SocketIO - 404 on Polling

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to add simple chat functionality in a previous project that used Flask through SocketIO. I'm having trouble integrating SocketIO correctly into my project. Although I'm new to Flask and SocketIO, I've been using python for a while.

**Error:**

GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1523266597636-12 404 (NOT FOUND)

**My Project Structure:**

```
├───config.py
├───run.py
├───app
│   ├───admin
│   ├───auth
│   ├───home
│   ├───static
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───img
│   │   └───js
│   └───templates
|       ├───base.html
│       ├───auth
|       |    ├───login.html
|       |    └───register.html
│       └───home
|            ├───dashboard.html
|            └───index.html
├───instance
└───migrations
    └───versions
```

Inside the `app` directory, `admin`, `auth` and `home` each have two files `__init__.py` and `views.py`. `static` contains all the CSS, JS and Images. `templates` has all the HTML templates that I am serving. I want the chat box to be in `dashboard.html` in `app`>`template`>`home`. `dashboard.html` has a javascript file implementing SocketIO.

**Main Goal**

TL;DR I would like to know where in the project should I add the .py files for socketIO. The .py file is referenced from the `dashboard.html` subfile above. Essentially, where do I place the SocketIO python script so that it serves SocketIO on the correct URL? (http://127.0.0.1/socketio/)

**What I've Tried**

1) Modifying the `__init__.py` in `app`>`home` and the aforementioned `dashboard.html`  - This leads to a 404 polling error

2) Adding new python scripts containing the socketIO code to the base `app` directory and using it in `dashboard.html` - Leads to a 404 polling error

P.S. The scripts are working because when tested in its own project, the SocketIO chat works perfectly. Let me know if you would like to see the contents of any file. I'd be more than glad to give you any extra information.

I really appreciate all the help!

Comment: Does app doen't have __init__.py file ? I belive you import your home ( blueprint or normal views ) to `app>__init__.py` Isn't it ?

Comment: `app` has it's own `__init__.py`. I'm creating the flask inside this file using blueprint

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so cool with python, but I had the same problem. I waste on it 3 days! 3 days of my life!!! : ( My issue was fixed when I update python-socketio library from version 2.0.0 (which was in my requirements.txt) to python-socketio 2.1.2

pip install python-socketio --upgrade

Perhaps this answer saves a lot of time for someone.